# pandas / numpy arithmetic mean in csv file

Tags: numpy, pandas, average, mean

I have a csv file which contains 3000 rows and 5 columns, which constantly have more rows appended to it on a weekly basis.

What i'm trying to do is to find the arithmetic mean for the last column for the last 1000 rows, every week. (So when new rows are added to it weekly, it'll just take the average of most recent 1000 rows)

How should I construct the pandas or numpy array to achieve this?

```
df = pd.read_csv(fds.csv, index_col=False, header=0)
df_1 = df['Results']
#How should I write the next line of codes to get the average for the most 1000 rows?
```

Comment: [Based on the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#head-and-tail), you should be utilizing the `tails` functionality of `pandas` to grab the last 1000 rows.

Comment: Thanks! I knew of the head and tail function. But didn't think i would be able to use it this way. Thanks Matt.

Comment: Cool. If the answer below helped you be sure to accept it (or if someone posts a better one) as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a different machine than what my `pandas` is installed on so I'm going on memory, but I think what you'll want to do is...

```
df = pd.read_csv(fds.csv, index_col=False, header=0)
df_1 = df['Results']
#Let's pretend your 5th column has a name (header) of `Stuff`
last_thousand = df_1.tail(1000)
np.mean(last_thousand.Stuff)
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit quicker using [mean()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv("fds.csv", header = 0)
results = df.tail(1000).mean()
```

Results will contain the mean for each column within the last 1000 rows. If you want more statistics, you can also use [describe()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html):

```
resutls = df.tail(1000).describe().unstack()
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically I needed to use the pandas tail function. My Code below works.

```
df = pd.read_csv(fds.csv, index_col=False, header=0)
df_1 = df['Results']    
numpy.average(df_1.tail(1000))
```